# Wiring for covered porch & yard lighting

Tags: electrical

I am hoping to get a couple points of clarification on a back porch wiring project.  This is in AZ, for reference.

In the photo, I am hoping to change the security light to a double switched receptacle - each outlet would feed a string of "cafe" lights, one for the covered back porch and one for the yard.  The existing install was done by a previous owner.

My questions are:

- Can I use standard galvanized EMT for this application, or do I need to use some sort of liquidtight conduit?
- Do I need to use outdoor/liquidtight (plastic) boxes or can I use metal handy boxes?
- If I need to use plastic boxes, I will need to run a separate ground wire, correct? (As opposed to using the EMT as grounding conductor?)
- Should the receptacle be GFCI protected?  If so, will I need to have a separate GFCI recept. that is accessible (instead of being up near the ceiling)?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EMT is fine. You do need to use EMT compression fittings for exterior work, IIRC The wiring inside the EMT must be wet rated, as all external conduits are **by definition** wet locations. But that's easy, just use THWN, as you are in conduit.

Same with the GFCI for all outdoor outlets, though that can be a GFCI at the breaker, of course.

The GFCI reset must be accessible (within 6'6" of the floor,) not require a ladder to reset it. Breaker would appear to be the easy option here, or put a deadfront GFCI down by the switch or below the breaker panel.

Comment: What about plastic vs. metal boxes?

Comment: An excellent illustration of why one question per question is the better way to ask, frankly.